# A relation named ... already belongs to this DataSet

Tags: c#

I can't fix this error that I get `A Relation named 'PlaneAirline' already belongs to this DataSet.` I have tried to change the name of the relation but I get the same error
Here is my code:

```
     private void getData()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter parentDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Airline", connection);
        parentDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Airline");
        SqlDataAdapter childDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Plane", connection);
        childDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Plane");

        DataColumn parentColumn = ds.Tables["Airline"].Columns["airline_id"];
        DataColumn childColumn = ds.Tables["Plane"].Columns["airline_id"];

        rel = new DataRelation("PlaneAirline", parentColumn, childColumn);
        ds.Relations.Add(rel);

        parentBindingSource.DataSource = ds;
        parentBindingSource.DataMember = "Airline";
        childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
        childBindingSource.DataMember = "PlaneAirline";
    }

    private void dg_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

   private void AirlineReservation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parentDataGridView.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
            childDataGridView.DataSource = childBindingSource;
            getData();  
        }
```

Could you please help me

Comment: Where did you define the variable `ds`? Are you reusing it across multiple calls?

Comment: I declared it as a class member "public DataSet ds = new DataSet(); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are calling `GetData()` method on `CellContentClick` event. This event will get fired `when the content within a cell is clicked.` Hence whenever you are clicking the cell your code is trying to add a relation which is already present when you first clicked a cell.

Probably you need to move the `GetData()` call to `Form Load` as given in the tutorial you have given.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have moved that into the Form Load like you said and now it works. But I still can't do what I want, it doesn't show me all childs when I select a cell/row

Comment: In your link, the assigning of bindingsource objects to datagridview.datasource i.e. parentDataGridView.DataSource = parentBindingSource; is done before calling GetData() method. Have you done the same way?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have updated the code with the changes I have made

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Not sure why it is not working. Maybe you can try raising another question regarding this. Also If my answer resolves your "original" issue then please mark this answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

On every click in your DataGrid (I'm assuming that `dg_CellContentClick` is tha click handler for the data grid cell) you're calling `getData`, where you try to add the relation `PlaneAirline`over and over again.

Try to move the lines

```
        rel = new DataRelation("PlaneAirline", parentColumn, childColumn);
        ds.Relations.Add(rel);
```

to where you initially create or define your variable `ds` (I think it's a DataSet).

Comment: I want to give you more details. I am trying to display all the childs of a selected row/cell. I have followed this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y8c0cxey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. I can provide all my code, but I don't think it will help

Comment: Well, this adds another problem to your questgion about the reason of the error. I guess you should open another question for that.